# On a number line ,what is sum, of all possible coordinates of a point p , if the distance from point p to 1/3 is twice the distance from p to 1/2

Tags: geometry

On a number line, what is the sum, in a fraction, of all possible coordinates of a point P, if the distance from P to t is twice the distance from P to L

Comment: Where's your own effort?

Comment: what number line are you using ??

Comment: Xy_ coordinat plane

Comment: that's not really a line except maybe in higher dimensional space at last check.  also what do you mean by "sum in a fraction" ? do you the amount of points in relation to the total points in the plane ( are you only considering integers  positive numbers ? or the real numbers as well ?

Comment: XY plane is *not* a number line and the answer will be different.  And how do you add up two points on the plane?

Comment: if we really wanted to complicate things ( we don't, we want to simplify it for ourselves and others) we'd ask you what metric are you measuring distance in.

Answer (score 0):

How do you write the distance from $p$ to $\frac 13?$. Similarly for $\frac 12?$ When you plug these into the question you should get an equation with two absolute values. Can you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, ... do it.

$|P - t| = 2*|P-L|$

$P- t = 2(P-L)$ OR $P-t = -2*(P-L)$

There are two solutions to that.  Call the $P_1$ and $P_2$.  What are they?

Now add up $P_1 + P_2$..